# Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object in Oracle Function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, privileges, sql-grant

I have function which i am trying to compile and getting an error as `Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object`. I am really not aware of this error and try to search for this issue but did not find any solution. I dont know is this related to any grant priviledges but i dont have priviledges issue to my schema tables.

```
create or replace FUNCTION "AK_CHECK" 
-- PUBLIC
(ID Number) RETURN Number
IS
  TYPE_ID Number := 0;
  SUCCESS Number := 0;
  S Number := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT ACTIVE(ID) + MANUAL(ID) INTO S FROM DUAL;
  CASE S
  WHEN 2 THEN
   SELECT TYPE INTO TYPE_ID
   FROM SALE_SUPPLY KD
   WHERE KD.KPI_DEF_ID = ID;    
  END CASE;
END AK_CHECK;
```

Comment: You are using `create and replace`, so if the function already exists, then it will be replaced. So, there is something else causing the issue and not the function name. Compile in `SQL*Plus`, and use **SHOW ERRORS**, it will show you exact line number and the object which throws the error. Edit your question and add copy paste the complete error stack.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably have another object with the same name (`PERFORM_CHECK`).

You can find it by quering `user_objects`:

```
select *
from   user_objects
where  object_name = 'PERFORM_CHECK'
```

Then drop it (replace `TYPE_OF_OBJECT` by the type of the object from the above query):

```
 drop TYPE_OF_OBJECT perform_check
```

Comment: OP is using `create or replace` for the function. If it already exists, the function will be replaced. There is something else which is causing the issue.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: And what if there is a table with that exact name? It will fail with this error.

Comment: @Rahul: need more help?

Comment: Hello Patrick i tried everything. I also try to drop but i am getting the same error :(

Comment: What was the result of the query?

Comment: Which query ? The Select query you wrote ? It returns nothing

Comment: In my case I was trying to create or replace function but a procedure with the same name existed.

Comment: I see similar issue even if I drop the object