# Flyway "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object"

Tags: flyway, ora-00955

We are trying to use Flyway to manage our database schema updates with the following spring-boot configuration:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        password: ${java_user_password}
        url: ${DB_URL}
        username: JAVA_USER

    flyway:
        locations: classpath:/db/migration
        user: SUPER_USER
        password: ${password_of_super_user}
        baseline-on-migrate: true
        url: ${DB_URL}
        schema: JAVA_USER
```

Flyway version 5.1.4.

The configuration is working in Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 Standard Edition but not in Enterprise edition. We keep getting the following error:

> SQL State  : 42000
>   Error Code : 955
>   Message    : ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
>   Line       : 17
>   Statement  : CREATE TABLE "JAVA_USER"."flyway_schema_history" (
>       "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
>       "version" VARCHAR2(50),
>       "description" VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
>       "type" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
>       "script" VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL,
>       "checksum" INT,
>       "installed_by" VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
>       "installed_on" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
>       "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
>       "success" NUMBER(1) NOT NULL
>   )

Any idea why? Before starting the spring-boot application we delete all objects under the schemas.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the select statement from this answer? Does it return anything? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30705316/5902456