# ORA-00955 Erorr

Tags: asp.net-core, oracle-sqldeveloper, razor-pages

Im trying to make migration from visual Studio. Im building a project with `Razor pages ASP.NET Core With Oracle database` and when i make the migration comes this error:

```
2020-03-17 22:32:15.351073 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleRelationalCommand.Execute() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00955: Es gibt bereits ein Objekt mit diesem Namen
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, DbCommandMethod executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
```

Comment: As `ORA-00955: Name is Already Used by an Existing Object`suggests, you are trying to create a table, view, index, synonym or other object that has a name that is already in use. As previously stated, database objects must have unique identifying names. Try [the solution in this link](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00955-name-is-already-used-by-an-existing-object/) and  the workaround provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705219/error-ora-00955-name-is-already-used-by-an-existing-object-in-oracle-function) which may be helpful.

Comment: Hi Mohammad Murtaza,
but I have deleted all the Tables from the database then I did the Migration and still the same failure. so where is the existing name i dont really know